# Produce Separate Results For Multiple Values

Tags: postgresql, syntax

I am attempting to produce multiple results for each value.
Postgres

Select count (*) from table_name
Where column_id IN(value1, value2, value3)

Looks like the outputs are adding everything together and I'd like the individual results for each value.

I was expecting the output for value 1, value 2, and value 3 not the combined sum, the individual values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use either a `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT column_id, count(*)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_id IN (value1, value2, value3)
GROUP BY column_id
```

or run multiple separate counts

```
SELECT
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE column_id = value1) AS value1_count,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE column_id = value2) AS value2_count,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE column_id = value3) AS value3_count
FROM table_name
```